# SQL Extract & Convert string to a number then use it for calculation to generate a third column

Tags: casting, substring, charindex

I have:

```
col1(varchar), col2(float)
25-PACK      , 4
```

want to have:

```
col1 , col2, col3
25   , 4   , 100
```

This is what I have:

```
CAST(SUBSTRING(col1, CHARINDEX('-P',col1)-2 ,2) AS FLOAT) AS NewCol1, Col2, Col2*NewCol1 AS Col3
```

The issue here is NewCol1 is an invalid name.  How do I resolve this issue?  TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
CAST(SUBSTRING(col1, CHARINDEX('-P',col1)-2 ,2) AS FLOAT) AS NewCol1, Col2, Col2*CAST(SUBSTRING(col1, CHARINDEX('-P',col1)-2 ,2) AS FLOAT) AS Col3
```

Comment: Is there a better way to do this, say I want a 4th column= col3*10, then my select statement will become very long.